# PHP optional function arguments with array. How to code / Better way to code?

Tags: php, web-applications

I'm sure there is a better to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I want to pass an array to a php function that contains the argument and all the arguments are optional. I'm using code ignitor and am by no means an expert. Below is what i have been using so far:

```
function addLinkPost($postDetailArray) {

    if (isset($postDetailArray['title'])) {
        $title = $postDetailArray['title']; }
    else {
        $title = "Error: No Title";
    }

    if (isset($postDetailArray['url'])) {
        $url        = $postDetailArray['url'];
    } else {
        $url        = "no url";
    }
    if (isset($postDetailArray['caption'])) {
        $caption    = $postDetailArray['caption'];
    } else {
        $caption    = "";
    }
    if (isset($postDetailArray['publish'])) {
        $publish    = $postDetailArray['publish'];
    } else {
        $publish    = TRUE;
    }
    if (isset($postDetailArray['postdate'])) {
        $postdate   = $postDetailArray['postdate'];
    } else {
        $postdate   = "NOW()";
    }
    if (isset($postDetailArray['tagString'])) {
        $tagString  = $postDetailArray['tagString'];
    } else {
        $tagString = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function addLinkPost(array $postDetailArray)
{
    $fields = array(
        'key' => 'default value',
        'title' => 'Error: No Title',
    );

    foreach ($fields as $key => $default) {
        $$key = isset($postDetailArray[$key]) ? $postDetailArray[$key] : $default;
    }
}
```

Simply edit the $fields array with your key and its default value.

Comment: You should be a bit careful doing stuff like this, especially if the data is user-supplied, because it is similar to register_globals.

Comment: @Tom Although personally I'd implement it using an array to store the values as opposed to the function local variable scope he used in his question and I used in my response, you could implement a quick check in the foreach loop to ignore any supplied keys that are not in the $fields array

Comment: Actually on second thought my example iterates over the $fields array as opposed to $postDetailArray so the key check wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 27):

You can use an array of defaults and then merge the argument array with the defaults. The defaults will be overridden if they appear in the argument array. A simple example:

```
$defaults = array(
    'foo' => 'aaa',
    'bar' => 'bbb',
    'baz' => 'ccc',
);

$options = array(
    'foo' => 'ddd',
);


$merged = array_merge($defaults, $options);

print_r($merged);

/*

Array
(
    [foo] => ddd
    [bar] => bbb
    [baz] => ccc
)

*/
```

In your case, that would be:

```
function addLinkPost($postDetailArray) {
    static $defaults = array(
        'title'     => 'Error: No Title',
        'url'       => 'no url',
        'caption'   => '',
        'publish'   => true,
        'postdate'  => 'NOW()',
        'tagString' => '',
    );

    $merged = array_merge($defaults, $postDetailArray);

    $title     = $merged['title'];
    $url       = $merged['url'];
    $caption   = $merged['caption'];
    $publish   = $merged['publish'];
    $postdate  = $merged['postdate'];
    $tagString = $merged['$tagString'];
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.  You get the desired result and you get a very readable summary of what the default values are.  It's essentially letting PHP do for you instead of looping, yourself.  PHP provides so many wonderful array functions, that I abhor looping over an array -- whenever I see looping through an array, I smell something that can probably be replaced by native array functions.

Comment: Agree - this is by far the most readable way to do this. Less LOC is not always better.

Comment: Elegant! Note, however, that a use of a separate "merged' array is not strictly necessary. I'm adding the following as a drop-in improvement to my existing code:
$argsR = array_merge ($defaultsR, $argsR;
($argsR being the existing function arguments array passed to and processed by the existing function).

Answer (score 4):

Using the array as an argument is a good idea in this case. However, you could simplify the code in the function a bit by using the ternary operator (http://dk.php.net/ternary):

$title = isset($postDetailArray['title']) ? $postDetailArray['title'] : 'Error: No Title';

You could simplify it even more by doing the following:

```
function addLinkPost($data) {

$arguments = array('title', 'url', 'caption', 'publish', 'postdate', 'tagString');

foreach ($arguments as $value) {
    $$value = isset($data[$value]) ? $data[$value] : 'Error: No '.$value;
}
```

}

Comment: Just noticed that it shouldn't be 'Error: No ...' for all of the options, but still... You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function getdefault($value, $default = null) {
  return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}

function addLinkPost($postDetailArray) {
  $title = getdefault($postDetailArray['title'], 'Error: No Title');
  $url = getdefault($postDetailArray['url'], 'no url');
  $caption = getdefault($postDetailArray['caption'], '');
  $publish = getdefault($postDetailArray['publish'], TRUE);
  $postdate = getdefault($postDetailArray['postdate'], 'NOW()');
  $tagString = getdefault($postDetailArray['tagString'], '');
}
```

or alternatively:

```
$defaults = array(
  'title' => 'Error: No Title',
  'url' => 'no url',
  'caption' => '',
  'publish' => TRUE,
  'postdate' => 'NOW()',
  'tagString' => '',
);

function addLinkPost($postDetailArray) {
  global $defaults;
  foreach ($defaults as $k => $v) {
    $$k = isset($postDetailArray[$k]) ? $postDetailArray[$k] : $v;
  }
}
```

With the one warning that if you have an array key of 'defaults' in `$defaults`, it will overwrite the global `$defaults`.

Comment: That (`$postDetailArray['title']`) would issue a Notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addLinkPost($postDetailArray) {

   foreach($array as $key=>$value){
     $$key = (isset($value) && !empty($value)) ? $value : ('no '.$key);
   }
   //all keys are available as variables 
   var_dump($url); var_dump($publish); //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make all elements of the array parameters of the function. Check if the first is an array in the function and if so, extract the array.

```
 function addLinkPost($title = null, $url = null, $caption = null, $publish = null, $postDate = null, $tagString = null)
 {
      if(is_array($title)) {
           extract($title);
      }

      ....
 }
```

Maybe that makes the code a little more clear.